# Can men wear artificial jewellery?

Tags: men, halal-haram, fashion-design

Can I wear artificial jewellery like a steel ring or a steel chain. I know that wearing gold or real jewellery is haram for men. But I've seen thousands of wearing steel jewellery. The question is can I also wear artificial chains and rings or it is haram?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know if they are the same, but it is permissible for men to wear silver.
I am not very well educated on the matter of men wearing jewelry though.[source](https://www.dar-alifta.org/Foreign/ViewFatwa.aspx?ID=10429)